# Break up nested list from the parent using for-each-group

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a xml like this,

```
<doc>
    <list list-type="alpha-lower">
        <list-item>
            <label>a)</label>
            <p>text1</p>
            <list list-type="order">
                <list-item>
                    <label>1)</label>
                    <p>text2</p>
                </list-item>
                <list-item>
                    <label>2)</label>
                    <p>text3</p>
                </list-item>
                <list-item>
                    <label>3)</label>
                    <p>text4</p>
                </list-item>
            </list>
        </list-item>
        <list-item>
            <label>b)</label>
            <p>text5</p>
            <list list-type="order">
                <list-item>
                    <label>1)</label>
                    <p>text6</p>
                </list-item>
                <list-item>
                    <label>2)</label>
                    <p>text7</p>
                </list-item>
                <list-item>
                    <label>3)</label>
                    <p>text8</p>
                </list-item>
            </list>
        </list-item>
    </list>
</doc>
```

Here there are nested lists exists and I need to break up the nested list from the parent list.

Here is my expected output.

```
<doc>
    <list list-type="alpha-lower">
        <list-item>
            <label>a)</label>
            <p>text1</p>
        </list-item>
    </list>
    <list list-type="order">
        <list-item>
            <label>1)</label>
            <p>text2</p>
        </list-item>
        <list-item>
            <label>2)</label>
            <p>text3</p>
        </list-item>
        <list-item>
            <label>3)</label>
            <p>text4</p>
        </list-item>
    </list> 
    <list list-type="alpha-lower">
        <list-item>
            <label>b)</label>
            <p>text5</p>
        </list-item>
    </list>
    <list list-type="order">
        <list-item>
            <label>1)</label>
            <p>text6</p>
        </list-item>
        <list-item>
            <label>2)</label>
            <p>text7</p>
        </list-item>
        <list-item>
            <label>3)</label>
            <p>text8</p>
        </list-item>
    </list> 
</doc>
```

I'm using XSLT 2.0 for doing this task and I tried to use for-each-group but couldn't come up with a solution.

Here's what I've tried,

```
<xsl:template match="list[descendant::list]">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="list">
            <list list-type="{current()/@list-type}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </list>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
```

Can anyone suggest me a method for do this from XSLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not use `xsl:for-each-group`, I used a regular `xsl:for-each`. Try this:

```
<xsl:template match="list[descendant::list]">
    <xsl:variable name="Ltype" select="@list-type"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="list-item">
        <list list-type="{$Ltype}">
            <list-item>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::list)]"/>
            </list-item>
        </list>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="list"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```